# Better method then long if statements in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

Im working on a game in which I have a canon that fires at difrent amounts of time. Instead of writing a long if statement like this:

```
If (time == 1) {
    "Do something "
} else If (time == 2) {
    "Do something else "
} else If (time == 3) {
   " You probaly get the point"
} else { 
   " My real problem is much longer than this. This is just. 
      an. 
    example"
}
```

So if there is an easier and prettier way to do this in c# that would be great. If not let me know also. Thanks in advance

Comment: If according to your requirement it has many different cases and the firing must be at specific times like `time == 1` etc then you have to use condition statements. you can create a separate function for it if you want. Thats all I can say without knowing the actual scenario.

Comment: A `switch` statement might be what you're looking for, it might not.

Comment: What I'm asking is, is there a way to make a list of numbers like 1, 2, 3. Than say if (time == my list). Is that a thing?

Comment: `Than say if (time == my list).` - what do you mean?

Comment: is `time` really and `int` value?

Comment: You could use a switch statement..

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments

 Using a [Switch Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) is probably what you're looking for.

```
    private static void FireCanons(int time)
    {
        switch (time)
        {
            case 1:
                // "do something";
                break;
            case 2:
                // do something else
                break;
            case 3:
                // you probably get the point"
                break;
            default:
                // My real problem is much longer than this. This is just. an. example"
                break;
        }
    }
```

Update:
Just looking at your comments, a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) may be better suited.
Here is a quick example I have made.

```
    private static void FireCanons(int time)
    {
        // A Dictionary That Will Hold Our Results.
        var myList = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            { 1, "do something" },
            { 2, "do something else" },
            { 3, "you probably get the point" },
            { 4, "My real problem is much longer than this. This is just. an. example" }
        };

            // Attempt To Get The Value.
            if (myList.TryGetValue(time, out string result))
            {
                // Display Results.
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
    }
```

Comment: No need for `myList.ContainsKey`.

Comment: yeah thats correct, I figured he may want to run a check to see if the key was there in the first place.

Comment: `TryGetValue` does this check. It returns exactly the same value as `ContainsKey`

Comment: Could I say:  new Dictionary<double, string>

Comment: You certainly can :)

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is another approach. Create Dictionary where you can register different actions for every value of `time`

```
void DoSomething()
{
    // Do something
}

void DoSomethingElse()
{
    // Do else
}

void  YouProbalGetThePoint()
{
    //  You probaly get the point
}
```

Register actions

```
var actions = new Dictionary<int, Action>
{
    { 1, DoSomething },
    { 2, DoSomethingElse },
    { 3, YouProbalGetThePoint },
    { 4, DoSomething },
}
```

Then usage can be one liner:ish

```
var action = actions.GetValueOrDefault(time, () => {});
action();
```

Such approach provide possibility to change behaviour of your code without changing the code in the function - Open-Close Principle ;)

Comment: doesn't `GetValueOrDefault` return the first value if none can be found?

Comment: `GetValueOrDefault` will return a value you provide as second argument, in the answer I provided a lambda which do nothing.

Comment: Wouldn't it anyway return not the first value but instead a **default** value (therefore the name) which would be simply `null` ? And than you could do `action?.Invoke();` so even if it returns `null` you wouldn't get an exception.

Comment: @derHugo, [Dictionary.GetValueOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.getvalueordefault?view=netstandard-2.1#System_Collections_Generic_CollectionExtensions_GetValueOrDefault__2_System_Collections_Generic_IReadOnlyDictionary___0___1____0___1_) - extension method which takes default value as second argument. Returning default value which can be used without null check will simplify the code and makes other developer's life happier ;)

Comment: I just pointed out that you could use the other overload without providing a custom default value and anyway will get a default value. In my eyes it would be cleaner code to properly receive `null` if there was no match and not even make an action Invoke if there is nothing to do anyway ;) but maybe this is just a question about coding styles and taste ;) this might change if it was about e.g. `float` or `int` where the default value `0` might not be enough to differ between a default and a valid result. There you might e.g. want to get negative infinite instead.

Comment: @derHugo, if both operations are in same method(retrieving and execution), then both approaches are good. But if "selected" action returned to other caller, then returning a valid value, but which doing nothing, will save consumer of the code from the extra logic branch, which probably need to be tested ;)

Comment: Might be true but at the same time it **hides** any other coding error since the actual problem here would not be that you return a wrong value but that you enter a wrong key ;) always returning a valid value hides this fact and might complicate debugging. ^^ I also find it easier to tell the OP it returns `null` if nothing was found than to explain how lambda expressions work :D but I see you have your taste I have mine ;) so this is just opinions here

Comment: @derHugo, sorry for being nitpicking, but OP's requirements are _I have a canon that fires at diffrent amounts of time_ - so cannon firing or not - default method(lamda or explicitly defined action) will do the job without introducing extra logic branch in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The current answers are fine ... to answer your question if `time` actually is an **`int`** value.

This is just a guess but usually when you spak about `time` you have a `float` value as e.g. from [`Time.time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html).

For this your approach using `==`, a `switch` and a `dictionary` as well would be completely useless since the odds that an exact time of e.g. `2.0` is matched in a certain frame is very close to `0`. (not even speaking about the [single floating point precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) here...)

For this you rather might want to have a look at [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)

You can create an [Extension method](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/extension-methods)

```
public static class MonoBehaviourExtensions
{
    public static void Invoke(this MonoBehaviour me, Action theDelegate, float time)
    {
        me.StartCoroutine(ExecuteAfterTime(theDelegate, time));
    }

    private static IEnumerator ExecuteAfterTime(Action theDelegate, float delay)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        theDelegate?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

and than simply use e.g.

```
private void Start()
{
    this.Invoke(DoSomething, 1);
    this.Invoke(DoSomethingElse, 2);
    this.Invoke(YouGetThePoint, 3);
}

// will be executed 1 second after start
private void DoSomething()
{ ... }

// will be executed 2 seconds after start
private void DoSomethingElse()
{ ... }

// will be executed 3 seconds after start
private void YouGetThePoint()
{ ... }
```

---

If you than want those to be executed again after a ceratin delay you could simply add a new call at the end like e.g.

```
private void DoSomething()
{ 
    ... 

    this.Invoke(DoSomething, 1);
}
```

or alternatively add another extension method to do so:

```
public static class MonoBehaviourExtensions
{
    public static void Invoke(this MonoBehaviour me, Action theDelegate, float time)
    { ... }

    private static IEnumerator ExecuteAfterTime(Action theDelegate, float delay)
    { ...  }

    public static void InvokeRepeated(this MonoBehaviour me, Action theDelegate, float timeInterval)
    {
        StartCoroutine(ExecuteInIntervals(theDelegate, interval));
    }

    private static IEnumerator ExecuteInIntervals(Action theDelegate, float interval)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);
            theDelegate?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

and than use instead

```
private void Start()
{
    this.InvokeRepeated(DoSomething, 1);
    this.InvokeRepeated(DoSomethingElse, 2);
    this.InvokeRepeated(YouGetThePoint, 3);
}
```

so `DoSomething` is called every second, `DoSomethingElse` is called every `2` seconds and `YouGetThePoint` is called every `3` seconds.